# English, Single word for - 'Hard to navigate'

Tags: single-word-requests

The route was ~**hard to navigate**~ and soon enough they were lost in the mountains

Comment: There is *unnavigable*, but that is generally used in a nautical context. You may have to settle on *difficult*, *unclear*, etc. Even better, don't tell your readers that the route was hard to navigate, show them why: impassable rivers, paths that petered out and turned to scree, overhanging cliffs, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Looks like you might be after [labyrinthine](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/labyrinthine) or tortuous, then:

> 1. of, pertaining to, or resembling a labyrinth.
> 2. complicated; tortuous

[labyrinth](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/labyrinth):

> 2. any complex or confusing system of streets, passages, etc.

[tortuous](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tortuous):

> 1. Having or marked by repeated turns or bends; winding or twisting: *a tortuous road through the mountains.*
> 2. Not straightforward; circuitous; devious
> 3. Highly involved; complex.

**PRE-EDIT**:

I suspect that [***arduous***](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/arduous) comes closest:

> 3. Hard to traverse, climb, or surmount.

Though I also rather enjoy *grueling*, it seems to be specifically focused on exhaustion - though that might at least work figuratively.

However, I would personally prefer you to help me establish "obstacular" in the lexicon.

Comment: Thank you for a answer, however arduous and grueling suggest a physical difficulty and my intention was that the difficulty is with finding the way.
The route not clear, confusing, and hard to follow. sometimes the path disappears all together, sometimes there are splits and turns not drawn in the map.

it is hard to navigate the same way a maze is hard to navigate.
Sorry for not being clear enough about that.

also i don't understand what the expression "establish obstacular."

Comment: In that case, I just found you something else and edited it in.  (The "obstacular" is just a joke - I was inventing a suitable word derived from "obstacle".)

Comment: *Tortuous* is good.